# How do you count the number of appllied filters globally?

Tags: dc.js

How do you count the number of applied filters in dc.js?

I couldn't find an easy way to do it, like

```
dc.countAllAppliedFilters()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. There's nothing built-in to dc.js to determine this, and crossfilter also doesn't provide any getters.

However, a crossfilter instance usually corresponds to a "chart group" in dc.js. If the filter count you want is a set of charts which are all interacting with each other, they are probably in the same chart group.

You can calculate the filter count on a chart group using the [(newly documented)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.chartRegistry) dc.js chart registry:

```
function chart_group_filter_count(chartgroup) {
    return dc.chartRegistry.list(chartgroup)
        .filter(function(chart) {
            // exclude focus charts because they will be counted twice
            return chart.filters().length && !(chart.rangeChart && chart.rangeChart());
        }).length;
}
```

If your charts are on the default chart group (constructed with only one argument), then you can omit the `chartgroup` argument.

The only tricky thing here is that we explicitly exclude focus charts from the count, because the range chart and the focus chart will always have the same filter, so it would get counted twice.

Comment: Thank you. In my case that would make no difference though as i only wanted to know if the number of filters is > 0